# Solidity solc compiler error on code Remix can compile

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs, solc

I am attempting to compile the following solidity code using solc in NodeJS.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract helloWorld {

  string public message;

  function constructor() public{
    message = "Hello World";
  }

  function sayHi() constant public returns (string){
    return message;
  }
}
```

The commands I've written in NodeJS to do this are:

```
var source = `source code above`
var compiled = solc.compile(source)
```

When I look at the 'compiled' object, I see the following errors:

```
formal:
   { errors:
      [ ':5:3: Error: Type "string" not supported for state variable.\n  string public message;\n  ^-------------------^\n' ] },
  sourceList: [ '' ],
  sources: { '': { AST: [Object] } } }
```

I have a working TestRPC instance open, and can run web3.eth.accounts from the node console to this TestRPC instance (over port 8485). The code compiles correctly in Remix. I'm following a guide on getting these libraries working on a windows computer, so I don't see why anything could be incompatible with one another.

The versions I am using are

- solc - 0.4.11
- web3 - 0.19.0

Comment: Could you try updating your compiler (solc), and change `pragma solidity ^0.4.11;` to `pragma solidity ^0.4.22;` (the latest version)

Answer (score 0):

The error you getting are from the function

```
publicsayHi() constant public returns (string)
```

~~~I think Solidity function cannot return type string.~~~ (I was wrong about this)

Comment: This is incorrect, Solidity functions can return strings

Comment: You are right. But why the error said.
`Error: Type "string" not supported for state variable.`

Comment: There are several sources on the web where people return strings, such as this one https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/8053/is-it-possible-to-return-a-string-from-a-function

Comment: I don't know, but I'm guessing possibly because it's an old verison of the compiler.

Comment: I spot something. `function constructor() public` Should this be `function helloWorld() public` ?

Comment: this is true for solidity 0.4.21 and earlier. but even so, it wouldn't produce the string error.